# Extracting filename string within a loop in R

Tags: r, string, loops, csv, merge

I am trying to write a code to create a new master dataframe (`master_adh_merge`) which merges all source .csv files within a folder `ROOT.DIR.MERGES`.

Source filename structure is adh-merged_YYYY-MM-DD.csv 
eg. adh-merged_2021-01-01.csv, adh-merged_2021-02-01.csv ... adh-merged_2022-08-01.csv

The data within a source file would be structured as follows and refers to a single month.

| Patient_ID | Site | Adherence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A_1 | Ax | 30 |
| A_2 | Ax | 0 |
| B_1 | Bx | 20 |

I want to strip the YYYY_MM_DD string from the each source filename, and paste this string into a new column for every row of data taken from that source file to denote the month from which each row is taken.

I would like `master_adh_merge` to look like this

| Patient_ID | Site | Adherence | Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A_1 | Ax | 30 | 2021-01-01 |
| A_2 | Ax | 0 | 2021-01-01 |
| B_1 | Bx | 20 | 2021-01-01 |
| A_1 | Ax | 15 | 2021-02-01 |
| A_2 | Ax | 10 | 2021-02-01 |
| B_1 | Bx | 40 | 2021-02-01 |

Each month I will have a new adh-merged_YYYY_MM_DD.csv source file  so I am trying to write a loop which I can run each month to keep updating `master_adh_merge`.

This is the current code

```
ROOT.DIR <- "/Volumes/shared/HAR_SP/SP/STU_cmp22rds/CFHH-extracts"
ROOT.DIR.MERGES <- paste0(ROOT.DIR, "/monthly-merges")
files <- basename(list.files(ROOT.DIR.MERGES, all.files = TRUE, recursive=TRUE))

master_adh_merge <- vector()

for(i in files){
  date_string = str_match(i, "([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).csv$")[,2]
  print(i)
  df <- read.csv(i)
  master_adh_merge <- rbind (master_adh_merge,df)
}

master_adh_merge <- data.frame(master_adh_merge)
```

When running this I get the error

```
Warning: cannot open file 'adh-merged_2021-01-01.csv': No such file or directoryError in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
```

I have checked and I am fully connected to the network path for `ROOT.DIR.MERGES`

I have run this code to check that I can actually access the files using the full `ROOT.DIR.MERGES` path and I can.

```
adh0 <- read.csv("/Volumes/shared/HAR_SP/SP/STU_cmp22rds/CFHH-extracts/monthly-merges/adh-merged_2021-01-01.csv")
```

When I try to do exact step using `ROOT.DIR.MERGES`, however I get an error.

```
adh1 <- read.csv(ROOT.DIR.MERGES,"adh-merged_2021-01-01.csv")

Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In file(file, "rt") :
  'raw = FALSE' but '/Volumes/shared/HAR_SP/SP/STU_cmp22rds/CFHH-extracts/monthly-merges' is not a regular file
2: In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '/Volumes/shared/HAR_SP/SP/STU_cmp22rds/CFHH-extracts/monthly-merges': it is a directory
>
```

Firstly, should my loop (in its current format) allow me to achieve what I am wanting to?

Secondly, from the error messages, it seems like how I am using `ROOT.DIR.MERGES` is incorrect, but I am not sure why.

Comment: You may need `full.names = TRUE` in `list.files` to get the full path.  Your code shows extracting only a part of the filename with `basename`, which wouldn't work if the working directory is not set

Comment: I have updated this line to
 `files <- basename(list.files(ROOT.DIR.MERGES, all.files = TRUE, full.names = TRUE, pattern = ".csv$"))`
but when I run the loop I am still getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `files` looks something like this:

```
[1] "adh-merged_2021-01-01.csv" "adh-merged_2021-01-02.csv" "adh-merged_2021-01-03.csv"
```

then, you can extract the dates from the `files` vector, and use `do.call()`, with `rbind` and `lapply()`, like this:

```
dates = str_extract(files, "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}(?=.csv$)")

do.call(
  rbind, 
  lapply(dates, \(d) {
    data = read.csv(paste0(ROOT.DIR.MERGES, "/adh-merged_", d, ".csv"))
    data$month = d
    data

  })
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have done this and now the `files` object now has the dates YYYY-MM-DD, which is great. Do you know how I integrate this string, from each source file, into the loop to create the `master_adh_merge` dataframe as outlined in my second table above?

I think I need to somehow bind the objects `date_string` and `df` in the loop

Comment: i already incorporated that.. , but I used `data$date=d`.. I can change it to `data$month=d`.  see edit; the result of that `do.call()` should be a single frame with four columns, the fourth one being `month`

Comment: the `do.call()` was showing an error when trying to read .csv files with just the date and not the whole file name. I amended the code `do.call(
  rbind, 
  lapply(dates, \(d) {
    data = read.csv(paste0(ROOT.DIR.MERGES, "/", "adh-merged_", d, ".csv"))
    data$month = d
  })
)
`  giving this result
`[,1]  [1,] "2021-01-01" [2,] "2021-02-01" [3,] "2021-03-01"`
 etc, down to `[20] "2022-08-01"` but it has not generated a data frame

Comment: sorry, I think I needed to return data in the `lapply()`.. See my edit

Comment: Thank you, finally could you explain how  turn this into an accessible data frame, which I can then write out as a csv?

Comment: not sure what you mean.. Just assign the result.. `merged_frame <- do.cal(.....)`, and then write it?  `write.csv(merged_frame)`?

Comment: Yep that worked perfectly, I hadn't assigned the result. Many thanks.